# #ApiRTC I can't change size of camera video

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have tried this tutorial, but when I pick QVGA or another, nothing happens.... The resolution remains the same

why can't I fix it ???

This is the source code

So I can see this function :

```
//RESOLUTION
            $("#QVGA").click(function () {
                console.log("QVGA");
                $("#resolution").html('QVGA');
                var constraint = {
                    'audio':{'mandatory': {}, 'optional': []},
                    'video': {'mandatory': {maxWidth: 320, maxHeight: 240}, 'optional': []}};
                webRTCClient.setGetUserMediaConfig(constraint);
            });
            $("#VGA").click(function () {
                console.log("VGA");
                $("#resolution").html('VGA');
                var constraint = {
                    'audio':{'mandatory': {}, 'optional': []},
                    'video': {'mandatory': {maxWidth: 640, maxHeight: 480}, 'optional': []}};
                webRTCClient.setGetUserMediaConfig(constraint);
            });
            $("#XGA").click(function () {
                console.log("XGA");
                $("#resolution").html('XGA');
                var constraint = {
                    'audio':{'mandatory': {}, 'optional': []},
                    'video': {'mandatory': {maxWidth: 1024, maxHeight: 768}, 'optional': []}};
                webRTCClient.setGetUserMediaConfig(constraint);
            });
            $("#SXGA").click(function () {
                console.log("SXGA");
                $("#resolution").html('SXGA');
                var constraint = {
                    'audio':{'mandatory': {}, 'optional': []},
                    'video': {'mandatory': {maxWidth: 1280, maxHeight: 720}, 'optional': []}};
                webRTCClient.setGetUserMediaConfig(constraint);
            });
//RESOLUTION
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your constraints are incorrect. I couldn't find any documentation that supports your constraint object. For instance here's the structure documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia):

```
{
  audio: true,
  video: {
    width: { min: 1024, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
    height: { min: 776, ideal: 720, max: 1080 }
  }
}
```

I tried the following, and they seem to work fine (for both Chrome and Firefox):

```
{
    "audio": true,
    "video": {
        "width": {
            "min": "300",
            "max": "640"
        },
        "height": {
            "min": "200",
            "max": "480"
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the live version of the code here: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/

On the other hand, if you are using any third party library, you should check their documentation for specifications about the constraints.